# I can't use my WIFI on my Asus please help

Tags: wireless, asus

Here it's the info !! please help

```
[sudo] password for anon: 
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Wireless-N + WiMAX 6150
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 67
       serial: 40:25:c2:69:a7:bc
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlagn driverversion=3.0.0-16-generic firmware=41.28.5.1 build 33926 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:51 memory:de800000-de801fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: AR8151 v2.0 Gigabit Ethernet
       vendor: Atheros Communications
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: c0
       serial: 54:04:a6:03:15:d0
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atl1c driverversion=1.0.1.0-NAPI duplex=full firmware=N/A ip=10.0.1.13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:53 memory:dd400000-dd43ffff ioport:a000(size=128)


anon@ubuntu:~$ rfkill list all
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wimax: WiMAX
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same wireless interface product as you have and after hours of Googling, I've found a solution. Start out by trying this temporary fix (won't survive a reboot) - open a terminal, and run the following commands:

```
sudo rmmod iwlagn 
sudo modprobe iwlagn bt_coex_active=0
```

If this works, consider making this permanent. I'm not sure how, but [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/922630) it is suggested to do the following:

> Go into `/etc/modprobe.d` and add a text file with this on a single line: `iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0`

To put this into a single command from the terminal (provide your password when asked):

```
echo "iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-askubuntu-q115315.conf
```

**note:** I see your network driver is called `iwlagn`. `iwlwifi` worked for me, but try to change it in case it doesn't work for you.

Comment: I've given your answer an upgrade and I think it's good in the essence. However, I'm not sure whether this will work in all `Hard blocked: yes` situations for this hardware. If it did for you, please mention this explicitly in your answer. Thanks!